# Remove the newline character in awk

Tags: bash, awk, formatting

I am trying to remove the new line character for a date function and have it include spaces. I am saving the variables using this:

```
current_date=$(date "+%m/%d/ AT %y%H:%M:%S" )
```

I can see that this is the right format I need by doing a echo $current_date.
However, when I need to use this variable it does not act the way I would like it.

```
awk '(++n==47) {print "1\nstring \nblah '$current_date' blah 2;     n=0} (/blah/) {n=0} {print}' input file > output file
```

I need the date to stay in the current line of text and continue with no newline unless specified.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `echo "$current_date"`, not `echo $current_date` to see the actual value of `$current_date`. The way you are trying to use the shell variable inside an awk script is wrong too. Post some sample input and expected output so we can help you.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than attempting to insert the variable into the command string as you are doing, you can pass it to awk like this:

```
awk -v date="$(date "+%m/%d/ AT %y%H:%M:%S")" '# your awk one-liner here' input_file
```

You can then use the variable `date` as an awk variable within the script:

```
print "1\nstring \nblah " date " blah 2";
```

As an aside, it looks like your original `print` statement was broken, as there were double quotes missing from the end of it.